# gant script with grails : includeTarget error

Tags: grails, gant

Creating a gant script to compile external module from a grails (v2.3.4) application:

> grails create-script compile

With the header below in the code:

```
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsInit")
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsClasspath")
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsRun")
```

> grails run script returns
>   Error executing script RunScript: No such property: includeTargets for class: Script1

Before that issue i had  one with Tomcat plugin dependency, which has been resolved by desactivating the plugin so as to execute the script.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you running the script? It appears that you're using http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/run-script.html but that's not for Gant scripts - it's for simple scripts that can access application classes. See http://naleid.com/blog/2010/12/03/grails-run-script-updated-for-grails-1-3-5 for the original blog post about this.

When you create a Gant script, it becomes a regular command like `run-app`, `create-domain-class`, etc. So you should be running your `compile` script as

```
grails compile
```

YOu probably shouldn't name scripts the same as ones included by Grails or other plugins. Grails will prompt you to ask if you want to run yours or the pre-existing one, but that's annoying; if you just give it a unique name it will be a smoother process.

Comment: if i rename my script to fsimulator.groovy, put it at the root's level of my grails project and launch ">grails fsimulator', console output says it's not found and proposes the pre-existing scripts only

Comment: Put Gant scripts in the scripts directory