# Configuring Grails create script

Tags: grails

Grails 2.4.5 here. Currently I use several Grails plugins with my Grails app, and doing a "full" local build requires me to run several Grails commands in a row:

```
// 1.
grails clean
grails refresh-dependencies

// 2. Codenarc
grails codenarc

// 3. Run unit tests
grails test-app -unit

// 4. If all pass, then build with lightweight deployer plugin
grails lightweight --artifactName=myapp
```

I would like to know if there's a way to (perhaps in `BuildConfig`) federate all of these separate invocations into a single `buildAll` command, and fail the build if any one of them throws `BuildExceptions` along the way (all of them do if there are problems).

Ideally it would be great if I could just do:

```
grails buildAll
```

And accomplish all of the 4 steps above each time.

**Note:** If you're all like "*Dude, you shouldn't have to `refresh-dependencies` each time, brah*" then I'm all like "*Dude, there's some major bugs in 1+ of the plugins that I'm using, so yes I do, brah*".

Comment: Why not create your own Gant script with `create-script`? That's typically what we do with multi-step builds in Grails.

Comment: Probably because I didn't know about it @JoshuaMoore (+1) ! So according to the docs I do `grails create-script buildAll` which creates `src/main/srcipts/buildAll.groovy`. But then how do I define those other Grails commands inside `buildAll.groovy`?

Answer (score 1):

Open your grails installation folder (GRAILS_HOME/grails/scripts). Within the scripts folder you will find many scripts which internally are using each other. Something like below.

```
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsInit")
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsClasspath")
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsRun")
```

You could also execute the scripts in similar way from your script.

For running tests look at some code snippet [here](https://github.com/jeffbrown/grailsnolib/blob/master/scripts/TestApp.groovy).

This SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20743084/gant-script-with-grails-includetarget-error) here should also help.

Comment: Thanks @Lalit Agarwal (+1) - but I'm still not seeing the connection between `grails test-app -unit` and `includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsRun")`...any ideas here?!? Thanks again!

Comment: Added a link to code snippet for running test using gant. https://github.com/jeffbrown/grailsnolib/blob/master/scripts/TestApp.groovy

Comment: Thanks again - would `_GrailsCodenarc` and `_GrailsLightweight` work here as well?